# How to center this image in div

Tags: html, css

I've tried alot of solutions and maybe I just implemented them wrongly for my code but I need help as my yr 11 task is due in 1 more day! Someone save me aha.
I apologize for not having a fiddle example to use as I don't know how to set it up or whatever, also the site just wants me to add more details so I'm just gonna keep writing till it lets me post cause I'm tired af and can't think. Whoever helps me your a bloody legend, cheers from straya :)

```css
.slideshow {
  display: none;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
  margin-top: -50px;
  font-size: 25px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.slide_selection {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px 30px;
}

.slide_selection img {
  height: 40px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 250px;
  border: #00000099 2px solid;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out, border .5s;
}

.slide_selection img:hover {
  background-color: #00000099;
}

.slide_icon {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  padding: 0 30px 0 30px;
  transition: all .15s ease-in-out;
}

.slide_icon:hover {
  transform: scale(1.3);
}

figcaption {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.slide_content {
  background-color: #00000025;
  box-shadow: inset 0 15px 10px -15px black, inset 0 -13px 10px -15px black;
  margin: -10px 0 0 0;
  padding: 30px 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

.slide_content img {
  height: 95px;
}

.slide_image {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.slide_info {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  width: 75%;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow">
  <div class="slide_selection">
    <div onclick="test(1);" class="slide_icon"> <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/iplpF.png" alt="" />
      <figcaption>WinRar</figcaption>
    </div>
    <div class="slide_icon"> <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/iplpF.png" alt="" />
      <figcaption>OllyDBG</figcaption>
    </div>
    <div class="slide_icon"> <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/iplpF.png" alt="" />
      <figcaption>NortonAV</figcaption>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide_content">
    <div class="slide_image">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/iplpF.png" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="slide_info">
      <h4>Software Type: </h4>
      <h4>Release Date: </h4>
      <p>Winrar Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
        aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can we see your HTML ?

Comment: It's already there... Also if anyone knows how to fix my .slide_content being glitchy at the start and end when I call slideToggle() onclick?

Comment: You need to include your jQuery...I thought your question was about centering an img inside a div, to which one of the 4 needs centering? The largest one?

Comment: Sorry. I'm going to delete this soon anyway because it's too messy it wont really help others and I'm pretty sure there's a cleaner example of using flex to center then this. All my code is too confusing aha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can I be consider as bloody legend?

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NpoGPr

What I did is use flexbox to center the image.

`justify-content` is for horizontal centering

`align-items` is for vertical centering

```css
.slideshow {
  padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
  margin-top: -50px;
  font-size: 25px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.slide_selection {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px 30px;
}

.slide_selection img {
  height: 40px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 250px;
  border: #00000099 2px solid;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out, border .5s;
}

.slide_selection img:hover {
  background-color: #00000099;
}

.slide_icon {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  padding: 0 30px 0 30px;
  transition: all .15s ease-in-out;
}

.slide_icon:hover {
  transform: scale(1.3);
}

figcaption {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.slide_content {
  background-color: #00000025;
  box-shadow: inset 0 15px 10px -15px black, inset 0 -13px 10px -15px black;
  margin: -10px 0 0 0;
  padding: 30px 0;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}

.slide_content img {
  height: 95px;
}

.slide_image {
  width: 25%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.slide_info {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 75%;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow">
  <div class="slide_selection">
    <div onclick="test(1);" class="slide_icon"> <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/iplpF.png" alt="" />
      <figcaption>WinRar</figcaption>
    </div>
    <div class="slide_icon"> <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/iplpF.png" alt="" />
      <figcaption>OllyDBG</figcaption>
    </div>
    <div class="slide_icon"> <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/iplpF.png" alt="" />
      <figcaption>NortonAV</figcaption>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide_content">
    <div class="slide_image">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/iplpF.png" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="slide_info">
      <h4>Software Type: </h4>
      <h4>Release Date: </h4>
      <p>Winrar Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis
        aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I really have to look into this flexbox stuff.. Works an absolute charm! Rhonda you rippah! xD

Comment: I also applied this to my slide_info and it even looks like a much better transition :)

Comment: @LiftedLemon I'm glad I was able to help :)

Answer (score 0):

i did nt understand your code but i think you need a div container you divise it as much as you need then you put your image in the middle of the page here is an simple example

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="igreen col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">this is will be green area</div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">step1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">step1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2"> <img src="my_image.png"></div>
    <div class="ired col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">this is will be a red area</div>
    <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">step1</div>
    <div class="iblue col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">this is the blue </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">step1</div>


</div>
this is a container
```